# Beginning jQuery help

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple MySQL Admin thing with php and jQuery. I've never used jQuery so my code is probably quite lol-worthy. The problem I'm having with the code is that when I click the button, nothing happens. I know the even fires because if I open the html file in firefox (not going to the url, using the file:/// thing) and click it, it shows my php code in the box I want the returned content to go into. The first thing i'm trying to do is connect to the database specified and return a list of the tables. Heres my code

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var Server = 'None';
            var Username = 'None';
            var Password = 'None';
            var Database = 'None';

            $("#connect").click(function() {
                Server = $('#server').val();
                Username = $('#username').val();
                Password = $('#password').val();
                Database = $('#database').val();
                loadTables();
            });

            function loadTables() {
                $.get("display.php", { server: Server, username: Username, password: Password, database: Database, content: "tables" },
                    function(data){
                        html = "<ul>";
                        $(data).find("table").each(function() {
                            html = html + "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
                            });
                                            html = html + "</ul>";
                        $('#content').html(html);
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div class='connection'>
                <form name='connectForm'>
                    Server: <input type='text' size='30' id='server' />&nbsp;
                    Username: <input type='text' id='username' />&nbsp;
                    Password: <input type='password' id='password' />&nbsp;
                    Database: <input type='text' id='database' />&nbsp;
                    <input type='button' id='connect' value='Connect' />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id='content'>

            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

**display.php**

```
<?
mysql_connect($_GET['server'], $_GET['username'], $_GET['password'])
    or die("Error: Could not connect to database!<br />" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($_GET['database']);

$content = $_GET['content'];

if ($content == "tables") {
    $result = mysql_query("show tables");
    $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    $xml .= "<tables>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $xml .= "<table>" . $row['Tables_in_blog'] . "</table>";
    }
    $xml .= "</tables>";
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo $xml;
}
?>
```

EDIT:
I have updated the code according to a mix of a few answers, but I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, firstly **don't do that** and by "that" I mean:

- Don't put DB connection details in Javascript; and
- Don't use input from the user without sanitizing it.  You're just asking to be hacked.

That being said, your main problem seems to be that `$(#content)` should be `$("#content")`.  Also putting an onclick on the button isn't really the jQuery way.  Try:

```
<body>
<div class='connection'>
  <form name='connectForm'>
    Server: <input type='text' id="server" size='30' name='server' />
    Username: <input type='text' id="username" name='username' />
    Password: <input type='password' id="password" name='password' />
    Database: <input type='text' id="database" name='database' />
    <input type='button' id="connect" value='Connect' />
  </form>
</div>
<div id='content'></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#connect").click(function() {
    $.get(
      "display.php",
      {
        server: $("#server").val(),
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        database: $("#database").val(),
        content: "tables"
      },
      function(data) {
        $("#content").html("<ul></ul>");
        $(data).find("table").each(function() {
          $("#content ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
        });
      }
    );
  });
});
</script>
</body>
```

**Edit:** minor corrections to the above and tested with this script:

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<root>
<?
$tables = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    echo "  <table>$table</table>\n";
}
?>
</root>
```

Comment: I made updates to my code according to you're answer, but I'm still having the same problem. The new code is in the question now.

Comment: You're adding a close </ul> in every loop.  Seriously install Firefox, get Firebug and look at your errors console.

Comment: Ok I fixed that, tried firefox with firebug, and looked at my errors console, and there were no errors, but alas, it still does not work.

Comment: Does going directly to display.php correctly bring up an XML document?  Do you have a single root element?

Comment: Also you don't appear to have an <?xml ... ?> header at the top of your tables document.

Comment: yea i realized that a while ago and just forgot to add it to this code. it's there, and yes it brings up the xml document

Comment: problem was that the javascript had to be after the html code. fixed. I'll accept your answer because i used more of it than anyone elses

Comment: Oh I see your $("#connect").click() wasn't wrapped in $(document).ready() or $() for short.  That's important.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.  I noticed three things about your code:

1) display.php doesn't close the  tag.

2) You refer to the 'content' div using $(#content), which throws a Javascript error.  Make sure to encapsulate this selector in quotes, like $('#content').

3) I'm not sure about "$("table", xml).text()".  Instead, used the very cool find('tag').each() syntax to walk through the XML response.  This worked for me as a replacement for your function(data) statement:

```
function(data) { 
    htmlTable = '<ul>';
    $(data).find('table').each(function(){ 
        htmlTable = htmlTable + '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>'; });
    htmlTable = htmlTable + '</ul>'
    $('#content').html(htmlTable);
});
```

Comment: Firebug is a great tool, I definitely used it while reviewing this code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working piece of code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function connect() {
          $.ajax({
                url:'display.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'xml',
                success: { 
                    server: $('#server').val()||'None', 
                    username: $('#username').val()||'None', 
                    password: $('#password').val()||'None', 
                    database: $('#database').val()||'None', 
                    content: "tables" 
                  },
                  function(data){
                      $('#content').html('<ul></ul>');
                      var contentUL = $('#content>ul');
                      $(data).find('table').each(function(){
                        $('<li></li>').html($(this).html()).appendTo(contentUL);
                      });                                        
                  },
                  'xml'
                });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
      <div class='connection'>
          <form id="connectForm" name='connectForm'>
                  Server: <input id="server" type='text' size='30' name='server' /> 
                  Username: <input id="username" type='text' name='username' /> 
                  Password: <input id="password" type='password' name='password' /> 
                  Database: <input id="database" type='text' name='database' /> 
                  <input type='button' onclick='connect();' value='Connect' />
          </form>
      </div>
      <div id='content'>          
      </div>
  </center>
</body>
```

But in my opinion it's better and easier to use JSON instead of xml, it's more easier to work with it (last lines of get function):

```
              function(data){
                  $('#content').html('<ul></ul>');
                  var contentUL = $('#content>ul');
                  $.each(data.tables, function(){
                    $('<li></li>').html(this).appendTo(contentUL);
                  });                                        
              },
              'json');
```

Also you can use jquery.form plugin to submit a form. It also can update specified elements using response, example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#connectForm').ajaxForm({
        target: '#content'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the question is. But you don't need the $(function() {}) inside your $.get callback - passing a function to $() actually binds an event handler to the "ready" event which only gets called when your page is first loading. You just provide a function that takes your XML as a parameter (here you have it as "data" but reference it as "xml"?) and use it. I'd start by reading http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype, and http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn. Also, install Firebug and check out the error console to see where your JavaScript is having problems - you can go to the "Script" tab and set breakpoints to see how your code is executing to get a feeling for where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(#content) // This is definitely a problem.
```

Selectors must be strings, so `$("#content")` would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jQuery.forms.js plugin.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/