# What is this kind of javascript? And Help with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I recently asked this question:

[Dynamically Query a Database to check for value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694849/dynamically-query-a-database-to-check-for-value/694860#694860)

And I got an awesome and informative answer. But whenever I search on Google to find out more about "Ajax Requests" the codes never look similar to the one provided. Also I have used another tutorial that used this, is it a shorthand? Or is it jQuery or what?

That horrible confusion, is messing up my ability so solve the following problem:

Sending the value of the field to the PHP script. I tried using something along the lines of::

```
$value = $GET["inputname"];
```

but that does not seem to work. Could you please help? I am very adept in PHP but I am very new to javascript. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.get(url,{},verifyDb);
```

is the [jQuery ajax Get method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype). You can pass a parameter like this:

```
$.get(url,{inputname: "value goes here"},verifyDb);
```

$ is a shorthand for the jQuery object. I would familiarize yourself with the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm an idiot but

```
$value = $GET["inputname"];
```

Should be:

```
$value = $_GET["inputname"];
```

Also,

> But whenever I search on Google to
>   find out more about "Ajax Requests"
>   the codes never look similar to the
>   one provided.

You need to be googling on '[jquery ajax requests](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)'

Comment: That was a typo in the question. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that by default Ajax requests are usually POST requests, not GET. So, in your PHP script, looking for `$_GET['blah']` ain't gonna work. Try `$_POST['blah']` and let us know if you find the vars you're looking for.