# Run DB Query function in background

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently trying to create a dynamic registration page. By dynamic, I simply mean that the username and email that is entered will be checked against the DB to see if they exist. I want to do this without redirecting to another page and so ajax with jquery is my best shot.

My system works as such;

- Query is performed to check for existence of identical username
- Similar query is performed to check for existence of identical email address
- If username exists, the string `ERROR_USER_EXISTS` is returned
- If email exists, the string `ERROR_EMAIL_EXISTS` is returned
- If neither exist, the string `USER_ADD_SUCCESS` is returned, and registration is done
- Regardless of the status returned, it will be returned in an array, and if registration is successful, there will be additional data returned within the array alongside the status message

I'm looking at [this example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694849/dynamically-query-a-database-to-check-for-value) by 'ClickUpvote' and trying to expand, but I'm having a little trouble. On my registration page, I've got a form, and for the sake of simplicity, I've replaced the 'submit' button with the link provided in that answer. This is the simple expansion I made to the script;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeAjaxRequest()
    {
       var url="./DoRegister.php";
       $.get(url,{},verifyDb);
    }

    function verifyDb(response)
    {
        if (response=="ERROR_EMAIL_EXISTS")
        {
            document.write('Email in use');
        }
        else if (response=="ERROR_USER_EXISTS")
        {
            document.write('Username in use');  
        }

        else if (response=="USER_ADD_SUCCESS")
        {
          document.write('Registration success');   
        }
    }
</script>
<?PHP
    echo '<form class="" method="post" action="./DoRegister.php">';
    echo '<div>'.EditBox('username','Username', False, True, True).'</div>';
    echo '<div>'.EditBox('password','Password', True, False, True) .'</div>';
    echo '<div>'.EditBox('email','Email Address', False, False, True, 'email') .'</div>';
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="makeAjaxRequest();">Check database</a>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div></div>';
?>
```

**NOTE:** `EditBox()` simply returns a HTML input box preformatted according to the parameters supplied to it. It simply makes the code easier to maintain for me.

The file `DoRegister` is in the same directory as the one this script is running in, and goes like this;

```
<?PHP
    define("base_path", dirname(__FILE__).'/');
    include base_path.'/core/CMS_Functions.php';            
    $_pagearray = _registerUser($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email']);

    if($_pagearray['msg'] == 'ERROR_EMAIL_EXISTS'){
        $msg = 'That email address is already in use. Please enter another.';
    }

    if($_pagearray['msg'] == 'ERROR_USER_EXISTS'){
        $msg = 'That username is already in use. Please enter another.';
    }

    if($_pagearray['msg'] == 'USER_ADD_SUCCESS'){
        $msg = 'Thankyou for registering <strong>'.$_pagearray['username'].'</strong>!<br>'.'Please click the activation link sent to your email address in order to activate your account.';
    }
    return $msg;
?>
```

**NOTE:** `_registerUser()` simply accepts the 3 parameters needed to register an account, and returns one of the aforementioned status strings. The parameters it accepts DO NOT need to be from `POST`.

My issue is that when I click on the link after entering details into the field, 'nothing happens'. I imagine that it's down to the form not actually being submitted through POST and so `DoRegister` never actually sees the values. This is the first time I've ever been into javascript, ajax, or jquery so it's not something I feel I can fix on my own (I tend to find that all languages I've learnt over the past few years have started off with something as simple as this though).

How can I expand/fix the script so that I can perform the 'dynamic' lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get the post data you want to send in javascript,

javascript is not my field of expertiese but lets see if i can do this...

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DoRegister.php",
        data: "name=" + $("#name").val() + "&mail=" + $("#mail").val() + "&pw=" + $("#pw").val(),
        success: verifyDb
    });
});
```

use your form like this:

```
<form action="" id="yourForm" mehod="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" />
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Should work, althoug i did not test this yet..

Comment: Close enough. Was able to work from it to a solution for my specific design :)